# name 'usr_name' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my while loop I want to add all the usernames that I will define from the usr_name.

```
#!/bin/usr/python3 
import os, sys
import math

try:
    project_file = open('work_good.txt', 'w+')
    text = project_file.read()

except FileNotFoundError:
    text = ('File not found')
    print (text)
    project_file.close()


def Zone():
    #Introduction to the database
    print ('WELCOME TO THE DATABASE', file=project_file)
    print (23*'=', file=project_file)

def Username():
    #Ask for users username
    usr_name = input ('What do you want your current username to be?: ').strip().capitalize()
    print ('Your username is: {}'.format(usr_name), file=project_file)

while True:
    my_list = []
    if usr_name in my_list:
        my_list.append(usr_name)



Zone()
Username()
```

The error says:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "project_work.py", line 27,
>   in 
>       if usr_name in my_list: NameError: name 'usr_name' is not defined

I have tried adding strings into my list, that failed. 
I have tried to change the variables name (usr_name) but it didn't work.

What I want it to do is to add any usernames into the list but I can't. How can I fix this?

Comment: `my_list` is always empty, so `if usr_name in my_list` is always `False`

Answer (score 0):

`usr_name` is defined in scope of `Username()` function.

So it is not available outside where you are trying to use it. You need to return `usr_name` from `Username()`:

```
#!/bin/usr/python3 
import os, sys
import math


def Zone():
    #Introduction to the database
    print ('WELCOME TO THE DATABASE', file=project_file)
    print (23*'=', file=project_file)


def Username():
    #Ask for users username
    usr_name = input ('What do you want your current username to be?: ').strip().capitalize()
    print ('Your username is: {}'.format(usr_name), file=project_file)
    return usr_name  # <---- return


try:
    project_file = open('work_good.txt', 'w+')
    text = project_file.read() 
except FileNotFoundError:
    text = ('File not found')
    print (text)
    project_file.close()

Zone()   
while True:
    my_list = []
    usr_name = Username()  # <---- get usr_name from function
    if usr_name in my_list:
        my_list.append(usr_name)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! Your help is greatly appreciated.